Is it possible to use prepared statements for table name?
I'm writing an json-api in rust with actix-web and mysql.
Is it possible to use prepared statements for table names?
Like in php with mysqli it is possible to use something like this:
SELECT * FROM ?? and bind the table name before execution.
Is something similar possible in Rust with mysql crate?
I'm using the mysql crate, but i'm willing to move to sqlx or something different, if it is neccessary.
I tried following code:
let stmt = conn.prep("SELECT value, lang FROM ??").expect("Failed to fetch");

let result: Vec<(String, String)> = conn.exec(stmt, (lang.as_str(),)).expect("Failed to fetch");

But its throwing
Failed to fetch: MySqlError { ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '??' at line 1 }
Also tried with only one ?

you cannot bind the table name in a prepared statement. When mysql "prepare" the statement it needs to know the table name already. Prepared statements are not just a variable replacement mechanism

?? placeholder is a client-side extension to query parameters and are substituted in via string interpolation as opposed to parameters of the prepared statements. Its implementattion is client specific, it has nothing to do with mysql.

Is there a function in rust-mysql or a different crate that provides the same functionality? If its on mysql side or client-side doesn't matter for me.
If not, how do i securely set the table name dynamically
